# Find string without function call

Tags: regex, swift

I tried everything, but my skill with Regex is bad.

My case is, I am trying parse files `.swift` to extract strings, and example I have a class with many number of lines, and in this file I have something like this.

```
let textReference1Count = "text 1".count()
let textReference2Count = "text 2"
let textReference3Count = "text 3".count()
```

I have this Regexp `(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1`, with it I can return all `Strings`.

The mission in this case is return only `Strings` without `.count()`

I read about `ˆ`, but every time I try use cancel all search.

Thanks advance

Edit:

Solution for this case is `(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1(?!.count)`

Comment: Look into negative lookahead.

Comment: Thanks @Linuxios I follow your tip and do this solution `(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1(?!.count)` :D Works fine!

Answer (score 1):

[www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html) provides a detailed explanation of one approach that can be used in this situation. 
When trying to match a pattern, but exclude some similar patterns, you can use:

```
ExcludePatternA | ExcludePatternB | ExcludePatternC | (TheOneIWantToMatch)
```

Then in the code that processes the results ignores the overall match, and only uses the match from the capture group.

In your case, the following regex should work:

```
(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1\.count\(\)|((["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\5.)*?\4)
```

It will match a string followed by .count(), or just a string.
When processing the results in your code, only look at capture group 3.
It will contain strings that did not have .count() at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when I try your example it find all `String`, in my case I need look only Strings without .count, I do it `(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1(?!.count)`